# Forms validation System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and JQuery submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a C# asp.net MVC web application, and I'm using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for form validation.

Here is an example of validation on a password field:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set;
```

In my View, the form has:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm() {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

I'm planning to use JQuery to Submit my form/model.

Example:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Update")",values,function(data)
{
    // do stuff;
});
```

My question is: will the built-in forms validation still occur, even though I am submitting the data with JQuery?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I assume it does. Since the validation is in the C# code, which is the server side. jQuery is client-side code. When you submit the request with jQuery, then the server-side code will be executed. But, as suggested by 'WannaCSharp', just try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. The validation in asp.net MVC is done as part of Model Binding. So, when you post your form data to the Update Action, the validation is done when the data is being bound to your Model.

You can read more about it here: [Validating Model Data in an MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)